# Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.3 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the error: `Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.3 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0` when trying to run the rails console.

How do I go about updating this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to run `gem update --system` to update Rubygems itself.